# G+ share bookmarklet for business pages

Tags: google-plus

We need a bookmarklet for easy sharing URLs on specific G+ business pages.

I've found an approach from Martin Stobbs here: http://goo.gl/xCvbL but this didn't work anymore.

So i was looking in the network traffic, when sharing on a business page, but unfortunately the requests are POSTs so it's not possible to use them in a bookmarkelt.

Comment: Try asking on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

Um, use this:

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/xxxxx/share?ur\l='+encodeURIComponent(location),
     'Share to Google+','width=600,height=460,menubar=no,location=no,status=no'));
```

Replace the xxxx with the first number in your Google+ page's URL.

Or use my (not very good) extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-on-google-plus-page/hemkpfchihlepkmclhjnhmemabkilobj